# How can I see inline completions with fish shell?

Tags: fish

I would like for what would normally would show up as tab completions, to show up inline in fish. For example, if I typed git, then add would show up, and if I started typing, subcommands that fit would show up.

I have not been able to try much, as no results answering my question have come up.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a feature that fish supports, so the answer is "You can't".